# Add UIImage below UINavigationBar bottom Swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I'd like to add an UIImage below my navigationbar.

[image]

So far, my code:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: 38, height: 38))
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
let image = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
imageView.image = image
navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

The logo is still in the middle of the NavigationBar, not below

Answer (score 1):

As [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624935-titleview) says, `titleView` will be displayed in the center of navigation bar.

`UINavigationBar` ignores frame of view which was assigned to `titleView` and layout it to center. You can create a view-container, assign it to `titleView`, and place imageView inside it:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: 38, height: 38))
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "logo.png")

let containerView = UIView()
containerView.clipsToBounds = false
containerView.addSubview(imageView)
navigationItem.titleView = containerView
```

Comment: it worked!! I just needed to define a frame for the containerView with the same width as the imageView, otherwise the imageView did not centered. Thanks!